# sql compare two table for different select

Tags: t-sql

I have this two table

One:

```
 ID                                     SystemProductID
 E57AD213-3953-481C-BA2B-4AF8B98A87B6   02188530
 2471F038-2646-4EC2-B245-4AF919901A71   02000099
 3A7D0896-EBB3-4E30-A535-4AF94FE83CCE   02025567
```

Two:

```
 SystemProductID
 02188530
 02000099
 02460103
 02460101
```

How to select some of that

```
IsExist SystemProductID ID
true    02188530        E57AD213-3953-481C-BA2B-4AF8B98A87B6  
true    02000099        2471F038-2646-4EC2-B245-4AF919901A71
false   02460103        NULL
false   02460101        NULL
```

Please tell me how to do this

full join is not working on what i want

Comment: You should post your SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my way of thinking, I always use what tables I know will have all of the rows of data and LEFT JOIN from there. I generally don't like RIGHT JOINs as they seem counter-intuitive to me. A FULL JOIN could work as well.

So, we take all the table two's rows and left join on the ID for table one where we can.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t1.SystemProductID IS NULL THEN 'false'
        else 'true'
    END [IsExist]
    ,t2.SystemProductID
    ,t2.ID                                     
FROM TableTwo t2
LEFT JOIN TableOne t1 ON t1.SystemProductID=t2.SystemProductID
```